# How to edit .doc file in iPhone

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

H Friends,

I want to edit the .doc
 files in iPhone and retain its format. I know its possible as many applications like "Documents to go" supports this. I am able to view this type of files currently.

Any hint in right direction would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're able to view them probably in UIWebView.
To edit them you'll have to parse them. Doc files as far as i know (at least the new office) are bundles with xml files and resources.

BTW what does your question have to do with cocos2d (tag)?

Comment: do u have any link as of how to parse it. I normally download it in NSData format.

Regarding the tag(cocos2d) it was mistake and I have removed it.